# Git New Branch and Amend

Tags: git

I wanted to execute the below sequence of steps is github but not sure how do i execute it since I am  new to using Git commands and how do I amend the comments

Problem Statement

```
Git: Working on Branch 

For on creating a new branch and pushing it to remote in Git.
```

- Your local git repository will be "test_app"
- Push the master branch of local git repository to the remote
  repository.
- Create a new branch with the name "new_branch".
- Make a change to the file (do not remove it), make a commit and push
  the branch.
- Amend the commit to change the commit message.

Comment: The last step: to amend a commit that is all ready pushed. Is not a good idea if others might have used that commit all ready. Otherwise just push you branches like with any remote. [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository)

Comment: It's not clear what the actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

- Push the master branch of local git repository to the remote repository.

```
git push orgin master
```

- Create a new branch with the name "new_branch".

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
or
git checkout -b new_branch
```

- Make a change to the file (do not remove it), make a commit and push the branch.

```
git add file
git commit
git push origin new_branch
```

- Amend the commit to change the commit message.

```
git commit --amend
git push --force-with-lease
```

The last step overwrites the last commit on the remote. And can lead to problems if others have fetched it all ready.